# Beans for multiple Cassandra Clusters with RESTful Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-cassandra

How do we connect to multiple Cassandra Clusters using Beans and how do we configure the Controller to use a specific cluster for an operation ? Do we keep these connections live ?

I have this CassandraOperations code:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:META-INF/cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "com.rg" })
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster() {

        CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {

        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(converter());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
        return session;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session().getObject());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your only option is configuring multiple `CassandraTemplate` instances that use multiple `Session`s. A Cassandra `Session` (and `Cluster`) and a `CassandraTemplate` have a strong 1:1 relation.

This will change will Spring Data Cassandra 2.0 as we're going to add a `SessionFactory` interface that is pluggable regarding its implementation so you can define own routing. Additionally, we will add an `AbstractRoutingSessionFactory` that is similar to [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html). See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-330 for further details and leave your thoughts in there.

Comment: What are options for the following scenario: 
I have 2 keyspaces in 1 cluster and 1 key space in another cluster. 
Should I :
1.) Create two Beans that give me the required connection to each of the clusters and three different template Beans that use different sessions to connect to the respective keyspaces in their clusters. 
2.) Create three different bean stacks (Cluster connection, session bean)

Comment: 3. bean stacks with CassandraTemplate. Depending whether you use Cassandra Repositories, you should also create three separate repository interfaces that are picked up with different `@EnableCassandraRepositories(cassandraTemplateRef=…)` annotation configurations with the according template reference.

Comment: Any good example for Routing Sessions